# Inconsistency in definitions of "critical points" and "differentiable"?

Tags: derivatives

A student of mine is in a class that uses the following definition of derivative: $$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
Their definition of critical points is "places where the derivative of a function is either zero or undefined".

Yet they do not list the endpoints of a function on a closed interval to be critical points. IMO, based on the definition of derivative, the derivatives of the endpoints are undefined and therefore *should* count as critical points. Is there an inconsistency here, or am I missing something?

Comment: For the definition of $\lim_{h\to 0}$, they probably just require zero to be an *accumulation point* of the domain of the function (in $h$) to which the limit is applied. And, yes, the ends of a closed interval are accumulation points of the interval.

Comment: If the function is not defined on one side of $a$ and continuous on the other side of $a.$ e.g. $\lim{x\to 0} \sqrt x$ the limit still exists (and behaves like a right-hand limit in this example).

Answer (score 0):

Although, in general, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ only exists if $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x) =\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x)$, and therefore $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ wouldn't exist at the endpoints, there are additional things to consider.

Usually, if the point at $h=0$ is an *accumulation point* in the domain of the function, then the limit is considered to exist. And the endpoints would meet this requirement.

In general practice, if a function is not defined on one side of a point and continuous on the other side, then the limit is still considered to exist, such as in   $\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{x}$.